# Why are my httpresponsemessage's content headers not added to the correct field?

Tags: c#, http-headers, httpclient

I'm trying to get a data-stream with a `HttpClient` but something odd is happening with the `HttpResponseMessage` I'm getting back.

The way I send the request is like this:

```
_webClient.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, _webClient.BaseAddress + connectionSuffix), HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
```

However the response's *ContentHeaders* are not filled the way I would expect them to be. Here's an example: The response contains a **Content-Type** header but it's value can't be found in the *ContentType* field, only in the generic *Headers* enumerable.
[image: visualstudio]

Analysing the packet flow in Wireshark gives me the following:

```
>GET /video.cgi HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46
Host: 192.168.0.150
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Answered with:

```
>HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: Camera Web Server/1.0
Auther: Steven Wu
MIME-version: 1.0
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=--video boundary--
```

It is not the end of the world, I'm after the boundary parameter and I can find it in the generic *Headers* field. But I can't help but to wonder: Is this intended behaviour? I can't seem to find any information about *getting* headers, only about how to add them to a request (which is a different matter)

Comment: Can you please check the response using a tool like fiddler2?

Comment: @OguzOzgul I've checked the response via Wireshark already. The device sends a correct response. I've included it in the original question.

Comment: This is interesting and I think CompletionOption is playing a part here. Why don't you ask this at connect.microsoft.com?

Comment: Probably this callback is invoked right after the http response header is completely received and while that, filled into the dictionary, but before it is processed into the ContentType or other properties. It is also interesting that the generic list only has the content type while other headers have been received as well

Comment: @OguzOzgul About the others headers. This is intended behaviour. A response message has response headers and content headers. Cache-Control, MIME-version and the likes are response headers, while Content-Type is a content header. This also makes me believe that this problem doesn't arise from accessing the fields before they are processed, because the response headers get filed into the correct fields, it are only the content headers that are not placed in the corresponding fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing of this header fails because of the whitespace in the parameter value of boundary.

This is not compliant with RFC2616, because the RFC states in [Section 2](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec2.html) that the header parameter values must not contain whitespaces or they should be specified as qouted strings.

Either change your boundary to

```
boundary=--videoboundary--
```

or to

```
boundary="--video boundary--"
```

and it works.

Note: You should remove the qoutes while reading the value for the latter.

From the RFC, Section 2: (LWS = Linear White Space)

```
Many HTTP/1.1 header field values consist of words separated by LWS or 
special characters. These special characters MUST be in a quoted string
to be used within a parameter value (as defined in section 3.6).
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I guess I'll just have to deal with it then, as I can't change the software on the other device, which is the one that chooses the boundary.

Comment: Yes. Warranty does not cover that kind of problems I guess. :) But at least you can report this to the manufacturer.